# How to create a custom keyboard shortcut for this nested menu item?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, textedit

I know how to create a shortcut; it is described on Apple website [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?locale=en_US). However, I came across a tricky case: I want to create a shortcut for the TextEdit application, particularly for setting the writing direction to `Right to Left`. The hierarchy for this is shown below:

[image]

I think that the problem is with the `Paragraph` word written in grey.

I've tried

```
Format->Text->Writing Direction->Right to Left
```

and

```
Format->Text->Writing Direction->Paragraph->Right to Left
```

and others, but none have worked.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `->` jumps into a sub menu, but `Paragraph` is not a sub menu. There does seem to be some visual division there, but I I'm fairly sure that `Paragraph` and `Selection` are just greyed out (disabled) and the other items in that list just have extra space (maybe a tab) in front to give indentation. I think you may need [Applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html) to do this. Clicking deep sub menus with applescript is pretty tedious, but you can click menu items based on the index.

Comment: I'm terms of indexes, I'm thinking the "path" is something like: `item 5 > item 2 > item 5 > item 4`. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Joonas, While one could AppleScript this, it isn't necessary to accomplish the task. See my answer to this question for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter that it's a *command* on a nested menu. Just create a proper entry, and in this case for the **Right to Left** *command* under **Paragraph**, it's:

```
'   Right to Left'
```

Without the single quotes and that's a leading tab space in front of **Right to Left**.

**Note:** You will need to copy and paste the `'    Right to Left'` (without the quotes from a text source other then this answer because AD converts *tab* characters to *space* characters), as you cannot key press a tab when creating the entry.

Here are some screenshots from my system:

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts]

[image: TextEdit Format Menu]

**Note:** For the **Right to Left** command under **Selection** there are two leading tab spaces, e.g. (without the quotes):

```
'       Right to Left'
```

The quotes in both examples are there to show there is leading tab space in front of the actual *command* names, although note that AD converts *tab* characters to *space* characters in these examples.

Comment: Great! It worked. However, for someone who will use this in the future, note that when I copied the menu item name from this answer, it didn't work because spaces -not a `tab` character- were copied. So, I wrote a `tab` character in TextEdit and copied it.

Comment: Can I ask how did you figure out the solution?

Comment: @ammarx, You asked "Can I ask how did you figure out the solution?", yes I used Xcode's Accessibility Inspector to copy and paste the value of the target menu command(s).